# how to pass the data variable in geturldata in vuejs in html part not any one is the same

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, vue.js

how to pass the variable in getdataurl in vuejs
A clear title.
A reasonable explanation of what your question is. Add as much detail as you can.
Any background research you've tried but wasn't enough to solve your problem.
Correct use of English spelling and grammar to the best of your ability.

```
<select-box
        title="CRM Prospect Status"
        v-model="form.crm_prospect_patient_status"
        getDataURL="/json_dropdown/crm-prospect-status/{{this.pipeline_id}}"
        :key=this.index ></select-box>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a computed property with your data.
like this:

```
urlData(){
 return "/json_dropdown/crm-prospect-status/"+ this.pipeline_id;
}
```

and then simply pass this computed property to your select-box

```
    <select-box
    title="CRM Prospect Status"
    v-model="form.crm_prospect_patient_status"
    :getDataURL="urlData"
    :key=this.index ></select-box>
```